# how to use css transition to show fast and hide slow

Tags: css, animation

I have a span which is set to `opacity : 0` and I show it when user hover on it, but the matter is I want to show it fast and hide it again slowly.

```
.mySpan {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#fff;
    transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0, 0.52, 1, 1) 0.3s
}

.mySpan:hover{
    opacity: 1
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the transition duration on hover:

```css
.mySpan {
    opacity: 0.1;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#fff;
    transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0, 0.52, 1, 1) 1s;
}

.mySpan:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<span class="mySpan">Hello</span>
```

On hover it shows fast as the duration is `200ms` but when you stop hovering it reverts back to `1s` and hides slowly.

Comment: thanks , could we wait for 2s after unhover and then hide element with 0.3s transition with css?

Comment: Just add `transition-delay: 2s`. You should read up on transitions.

Answer (score 4):

You can add different `transition` value on `hover`:

```css
.mySpan {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#fff;
    transition: 1s;
    padding:10px;
}

.mySpan:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<span class="mySpan">test</span>
```